# Why can't I rotate just one image by itself but I can rotate multiple images when using the Windows 10 Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, images, photos, rotate

I am having an odd issue in Windows 10 using the "Rotate Left" or "Rotate Right" Explorer right-click menu options. If I select two or more images, I can rotate them just fine using either method, left or right, but if I try to rotate just one image by itself, both options are greyed out. Why is this and how can I fix it? I know that I can open the image in a photo viewer and rotate it that way, but I would like to be able to rotate using the context menu as it is more convenient.

Comment: What type of images (jpg etc)? Have you installed any extensions to Windows Explorer? Try to see if this problem arrives when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: It's because the file(s) you're trying to rotate are read-only.  Not sure why Windows allows rotating read-only files when two or more read-only files are selected, but if you remove the read-only attribute, you'll be able to do so via individual files _(CTRL+A > right-click > select properties > clear the Read-only tick box > OK)_